# Doesn't Iconbuttons onTap method or any other onTap work inside a stack widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen which has a image on top of which i have a row with two icons wrapped with gesture detector and all of them are inside a stack. But whenever i tap on any of the buttons they dont work. Please tell me how to solve this.
Below is my code snippet....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news/ui/bookmark.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final String title, description, image, author, content;

DetailScreen(
  {this.title, this.image, this.description, this.author, this.content});

@override
_DetailScreenState createState() => _DetailScreenState();
}

class _DetailScreenState extends State<DetailScreen> {
List<String> list = [];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: size.height / 2.6,
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.loose,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
                height: size.height / 2.8,
                width: size.width,
                child: Image.network(
                  widget.image,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      print('Damn You'); //Doesn't work 
                    },
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.share,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Share.share('${widget.image}' +
                            '\n${widget.title}' +
                            '\n${widget.description}');
                      }), //Doesn't work 
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                list.add(widget.title);
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Bookmark(
                              list: list,
                            )));
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60.0,
                    width: 60.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        color: Colors.blue),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.bookmark,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), //works fine
      Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, bottom: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        child: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: Colors.black),
          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0, left: 15.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: Colors.grey,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            Text(
              widget.author == null ? 'No Author' : widget.author,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 15.0,
          right: 15.0,
        ),
        child: Divider(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        child: Text(
          widget.content == null
              ? 'Sorry this document has no content'
              : widget.content,
          //overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
 );
  }
}
```

How to solve the problem please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't have a closer looks but I remember issues when a widget overflows within a stack.

Comment: any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Where is the "Stack" widget? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: I think now you can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the InkWell() widget is hidden at the background of your container. And this is because it's referencing the top level Material() widget. All you need to do is instantiate a new Material() widget above the CircularAvatar() widget, therefore making CircularAvatar() its parent.

On your TopArea() widget, make the CircularAvatar() widget the parent of
Material() widget which in turns, makes the InkWell() widget its child.

Example below

```
 Widget topArea() { 
    return Row( 
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[ 
      // Other top widget codes goes here

       CircleAvatar( 
          radius: 25.0, 
          //backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, 
           backgroundImage: NetworkImage( "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1138409/pexels-photo- 1138409.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260", ), 
         child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: InkWell( 
               onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => {})),
              highlightColor: Colors.red[200].withOpacity(0.5),
              splashColor: Colors.red[200].withOpacity(0.5),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
              radius: 25.0
          )
        ),

      ),
   ],
 );
}
```

UPDATED:

Instead of GestureDectector(), try this below

```
 IconButton(
   icon: Icon( Icons.arrow_back),
   color: Colors.white, 
   onPressed: () { print('Hello World')}
 )
```

When you run your app, check your console if "Hello World" is printed when the button is clicked.

Comment: please check the code i uploaded again help me

Comment: Instead of GestureDetector() widget try using Iconbutton() widget. and changed the onTap to onPressed.

Comment: already tried but the result is the same

Comment: The third widget in the stack is wrongly implemented. You can't use "child: Padding()" inside of a Stack widget children list.   Try commenting out that entire widget and try it again.

Comment: but that button is working properly...The second widget which is in a row is not working 'The share button and the back button'

Comment: Which of the button is working properly? I can only see two buttons on your code sample. So if you click on your back button nothing is printed to your console? Please can I see the updated code? I want to see if you actually did what I said.

Comment: i have updated the code and specified the exact location of the problem with //doesnt work comment...

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it

Comment: i found the issue bro it was because of the bookmark button,as this button was the top of the stack the row which was next in the stack was not working.

Comment: OK. Great, but I told you to comment it out earlier on this comment thread. Great you were able to resolve it. Cheers.

Comment: ya anyway thanks for responding bro....